# Understanding XML format

Tags: xml

For something like this: http://was-sg.wascdn.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Slide046.png

Would the representation be like:

```
<continent value="Internet Users In Europe">
    <country name="United Kingdom">
        <users>55 Million</users>
    </country>
    <country name="Ireland">
        <users>3.7 Million</users>
    </country>
    <country name="Norway">
        <users>4.5 Million</users>
    </country>
    <country name="Germany">
        <users>68 Million</users>
    </country>
</continent>
```

then how can this be embedded in an html file?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I will change that real quick! Silly mistake.

Comment: It depends on how you are going to use it. You might simply place it between `<div>` and `</div>` and use DOM to select the nodes. Or you might need to declare a namespace or even prefix your elements if you are using a strict XHTML page.

Comment: @helderdarocha I'm just going to display the information on the page. This is my first time with XML and not sure how formatting within the HTML can be done (or if at all). But is the set up of the elements correct, or are there strict tags that have to be used. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using XML directly embedded in an HTML page:

```
<html> ...
  <body> ...
    <div id="xml-data">
        <continent value="Internet Users In Europe">
            <country name="United Kingdom">
                <users>55 Million</users>
            </country>
            <country name="Ireland">
                <users>3.7 Million</users>
            </country>
            <country name="Norway">
                <users>4.5 Million</users>
            </country>
            <country name="Germany">
                <users>68 Million</users>
            </country>
        </continent>
    </div>
    ...
</body>
```

You can style it with CSS (but be aware that many newer CSS tricks may not work with arbitrary XML tags - to be safe, stick with CSS2 and test in multiple browsers):

```
continent {
    display: block;
    border: solid black 1px;
    width: 250px;
}
country {
    display: block;
}
country {
    display: block;
    border: solid black 1px;
    padding: 2px;
    text-align: center;
}

country:before {
    display: block;
    content: attr(name);
}
```

And you can use scripts to change its structure, add and remove elements and atrributes, respond to events, etc. Here's a simple example:

```
var countries = document.getElementsByTagName("country");
for(i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
    var attr = countries[i].getAttribute('name');
    countries[i].setAttribute('name', attr.toUpperCase());
}
```

You can experiment with this example in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/vZLYA/) and see the result of applying the above CSS and scripting to the embedded XML.

To use the data in the XML for the image you linked in your example, you would probably hide the XML (make the `div` not display) and use it to extract the data which you can position and style using CSS over the image. You could also use the data in the XML as a source for an embedded SVG image, and use scripting to copy the text to the SVG objects.